# How do you run SpecFlow scenarios from the command line using MSTest?

Tags: c#, mstest, bdd, specflow

I've got Visual Studio 2010, and we have two VS solutions we work with. The first is the web application, and the second is strictly for SpecFlow tests. Having two instances of Visual Studio running at the same time just to run SpecFlow features is eating all the available RAM causing things to slow down.

I've done some searching on Google and here on StackOverflow, plus perused the MS documentation on the MSTest command line tool, but I haven't found the answer. The full SpecFlow test suite takes ~45 minutes to complete, and I really only need to run a few scenarios.

I was wondering if there is a way to run individual SpecFlow features, and even individual scenarios, from the command line using MSTest?

Comment: You might also consider looking at NCrunch (http://NCrunch.net) or ContinuousTests (http://www.continuoustests.com). Both of these tools are designed to run your tests as quickly as possible. I use NCrunch which has an *only run the tests affected by my change* mode, and would be just what you are after

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Behind the scene specflow tests are just regular mstest unit tests. So you should be able to run them the same way using something like:

To run a specific scenario:

```
mstest /testcontainer:tests.dll /test:GivenMyScenarioWhenIDoSomeStuff
```

To run a several specific scenario you can use the /test flag multiple times:

```
mstest /testcontainer:tests.dll /test:GivenMyScenarioWhenIDoSomeStuff /test:GivenMyScenarioWhenIDoSomemthingElse
```

To run a feature

```
mstest /testcontainer:tests.dll /test:MyFeatureName
```

If you add tags on your scenarios using @MyTag for example, you could also use the option

```
/category:MyTag to filter down the scenarios to run.
```

Please have a look to the generated code behind of your feature files to get a clue of how things actually work, if you are familliar with mstest it should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: It looks like this is the answer, however I'm butting my head against another issue. I have installed all the test project's dependencies via NuGet, which throws all those DLLs into the "packages" directory. The `mstest` command line utility expects all the class libraries to exist in the current working directory. I installed the `SpecBind` NuGet package, which does give me the missing DLL file (SpecBind.CodedUI.dll) but it's not getting copied to my build directory. I'll have to do some digging into this unless you've got some suggestions (I'm uses CodedUI tests for this project).

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer, because I'm butting my head against a different issue -- probably one due to the setup of my Visual Studio solution. Thanks!

Comment: Use Vstest.console.exe instead of mstest. Vstest.console.exe will automatically load all your nuget packages as well as other libraries. E.g Vstest.console.exe mytests.dll

Comment: How do you do an "AND" or "OR" condition on the tags - if you wanna run multiple test case that have different tags?

Answer (score 8):

Now that SpecFlow 3.0 has been released we can use SpecFlow with .NET Core. The CLI tool for .NET Core is *dotnet* and tests are run like this if you use MSTest (vstest):

```
dotnet test
```

If the tests are in a specific project you can specify the project like this

```
dotnet test TestProject
```

where *TestProject* is the name of the project. You can skip the project name if you want to, but specifying it will make dotnet look in only that project. To list all the tests in the project you can use the `-t` flag:

```
dotnet test TestProject -t
```

To run only specific tests you can use the `--filter` flag:

```
dotnet test TestProject --filter ShouldBeSuccess_1
```

where *ShouldBeSuccess_1*  is the name of the test. The argument after `--filter` is an expression, and not necessary the name of the test If you had a test called *ShouldBeSuccess_12* it would also run. You can see the rules for `--filter` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/selective-unit-tests).

To only run the tests in a specific category you can use `TestCategory`:

```
dotnet test TestProject --filter TestCategory=ci
```

where *ci* is the category name. To add a test to a category you use [tags](https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/api/#tags).

To create the results file you have to use the `--logger` flag:

```
dotnet test TestProject --logger trx
```

Here it's used to create a trx results file.

Answer (score 2):

There is a nuget package named "Specrun.Specflow" download that. And it will change your app.config and set unitTestProvider name="SpecRun", so you can remove unitTestProvider name="MSTest" or "NUnit", now on saving App.config changes, visual studio prompts you to regenerate your feature files, click on Yes and now build a solution, What you will see is your test files have been regenerated.
Now in your Command Prompt go to C:\Users\\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ and type runtests.cmd , it should trigger all your Feature files directly.

Comment: Specrun.Specflow is the commercial product of Specflow and costs 150 dollars per user. This revenue stream appears to be why there is little to no support for running spec flow in any of the standard open source runners. Paid for runners is really unhelpful for CI environments and presents an organisational barrier to usage even for wealthy corporations. This of course is not your fault but I thought it should be mentioned as a major caveat to your suggestion.

Comment: As above, it's not helpful to deviate away from the original requirement and suggesting a commercial version as a solution. I'm still trying to figure out how to run the Specflow (with Mstest) features from command line

Answer (score 2):

With MSTest v2, you can´t use mstest. You can use **vstest.console.exe** instead.

Example:

> vstest.console.exe "Automation.SpecFlow\bin\Release\Automation.SpecFlow.dll"
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/vstest-console-options?view=vs-2019

If you want to run all scenarios in a single feature file, then add the `/trait` flag:

> vstest.console.exe "Automation.SpecFlow\bin\Release\Automation.SpecFlow.dll" /trait:"My Feature"

And this runs all scenarios in the feature files that begin with:

```
Feature: My Feature
    In order to ...
    As a ...
    I want to ...

Scenario: 1
    ...

Scenario: 2
    ...
```

Comment: Your answer reminds me. I figured out how to filter it to a single feature file too. I edited your answer to add that info. +1

Answer (score 0):

I tried the tags technique but it didn't work, I'm using an older version of SpecFlow. 
So, I went to the **.feature.cs** file related to a feature file and searched for TestMethodAttribute()

```
[Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestMethodAttribute()]
```

I added the TestCategory attribute on top of this, just like the following:

```
[Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestCategory("MyCat")]
```

Build and compile and the command worked like a charm with

```
/Category:MyCat
```

I hope someone will find the answer useful.

Comment: You should not edit .feature.cs file because it is regenerated every time you edit the .feature file. You should add a tag to the .feature file (as @someTag) and then the .feature.cs file will contain         [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestCategoryAttribute("someTag")]

Comment: It is possible to create a partial class separately and add attributes to that instead of messing with auto-gen files.