# BDD Tests are not recognized in command level

Tags: mstest, bdd, specflow

I am trying to run Specflow BDD tets in command line and looks like it doesn't recognized those tests. But I am able to run them in VS IDE

[image]

[image]

Not sure whether there is a path issue.

I tried other options as in the below link as well. No luck though

[How do you run SpecFlow scenarios from the command line using MSTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20613221/how-do-you-run-specflow-scenarios-from-the-command-line-using-mstest)

Comment: I have never used SpecFlow, but I suspect that the path is missing something.

Comment: @MPH Which unit test provider do you have configured in you app.config?

Comment: @AndreasWillich I haven't put anything specific there. Only `<section name="specFlow" type="TechTalk.SpecFlow.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionHandler, TechTalk.SpecFlow" ` apart from URLs

Comment: Use SpecRun runner from commandline instead. It yields far better looking reports, and is made to run in the console.

Comment: @PedroG.Dias I am using same withing my project already. Not sure how to use it for commandline. If could please give a bit of guidance or link.

Comment: http://www.specflow.org/plus/runner/

Comment: @MPH strange that your config is empty. Have a look at http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Configuration/ and configure it to mstest.

Comment: @AndreasWillich It worked after adding `<unitTestProvider name="MsTest" />` to  `App.config`, Could you please write as the answer then I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was, that the code-behind files of the feature files were not generated properly, because the configuration of the unitTestProvider was missing.

See the documentation for that here: http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Configuration/