# Console Application to launch Specflow features by code not using ncode runner

Tags: c#, nunit, specflow, ranorex

I have programmed an console application with c# for ranorex automation.

Within the exe i have build i would like to kick off the specflow feature files manually.

I believe I need to create a TestRunnerManager and trigger the run.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Although not familiar with nunit, I guess like with mstest, attributes are used to mark methods in an assembly as tests. You could use reflection to find these methods in the assembly and invoke them

Answer (score 0):

This question is similar in spirit to one I asked a while back about MsTest ([How do you run SpecFlow scenarios from the command line using MSTest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20613221/how-do-you-run-specflow-scenarios-from-the-command-line-using-mstest)).

Remember that SpecFlow feature files become C# classes. Scenarios within a feature file become test methods. You can use the `nunit-console` command line utility to run these:

```
nunit-console /fixture:Your.Test.Project Your.Test.Project.dll
```

Which should run all the tests in the `Your.Test.Project` namespace.

When annotating scenarios using `@CategoryName`:

```
@Feature1
Scenario: Some cool feature
    Given ...
```

You should be able to run those from the command line as well:

```
nunit-console /include:Feature1 Your.Test.Project.dll
```

---

**Note:** This is from an older version of NUnit. Current documentation: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Command-Line

---

I use MsTest with Specflow, so my examples might not be correct, but this should put you on the right path. Just look at the `*.feature.cs` files generated by the .feature file to give you some hints.

No need to create your own console application to run these tests. Worst case scenario, create a batch file or PowerShell script to kick off the tests you want.